# AngularJS select2 ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

Can any body help me with sample code?

I want to select country with AngularJS ui select2 and upon select, the corresponding state is loaded on a different select2 for state. And the country and state are located in a JSON data. The state has a Country Id.

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: i actually need the concept so that i can start my design, something like a template design that i can follow the structure or the model

Comment: I've tried a blind answer since you did not provide much. If you have more specific elements it may be nice

Answer (score 1):

Something like the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) says? Assuming that you have an object `data` in your scope.

Data structure

```
{
    "countries": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "US",
            "states": [
                {"id": 1, "name"="CA"}
                {"id": 2, "name"="NJ"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "UK",
            "states": [
                {"id": 1, "name"="London"}
                {"id": 2, "name"="Manchester"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

HTML View

```
<select ui-select2 ng-model="countryPicked" data-placeholder="Pick a country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="country in data.countries" value="{{country.id}}">{{country.name}}    </option>
</select>
<select ui-select2 ng-model="statePicked" data-placeholder="Pick a state" ng-if="country">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat="state in data.countries[countryPicked]" value="{{state.id}}">{{state.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>Country picked: {{ countryPicked }}</p>
<p>State picked: {{ statePicked }}</p>
```